# when I have installed jdk 13 but in cmd it shows the version of java 7

Tags: java, eclipse, android-studio, sdk

I want to use ecplise and android studio in windows 7 64-bit. and I have downloaded 70 gig package of sdk and installed jdk 7,8, 12 ,and 13. but no sdk platform is shown on sdk manager of android studio and eclipse doesn't even open due to lack of jdk. 
when I use java -version in cmd: it shows jdk 1.7.. 
I have  set java_home too

what is the problem?

Comment: Are those 64-bit JDKs? And none of those are _Android_ SDKs.

Comment: jdk-7u80-windows-x64, jdk-12_windows-x64_bin,

Comment: Have you set your  "Environment variables " ? to the version that you want? If you have , `java -version` never shows the wrong version.